# How to Prevent "sqlite_config failed error_code = 21. THIS SHOULD NEVER occur" errors

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

This unhelpful error message has been driving me crazy recently; it does not occur within the android emulator, only when running on my (android 2.3.6) device via USB debugging, launched from Eclipse.

No exceptions are actually being thrown, and as far as I can tell none of my database queries are actually failing (everything seems to be working normally), yet I'm receiving at least one of these error for every query that I run.

As far as I can tell I'm doing everything right:

- I'm using one `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance created as a singleton (synchronised static method retrieves a single instance using the application's context).
- I only call `getWritableDatabase()` when I need to run an `update`, `insert` etc., the rest of the time I use `getReadableDatabase()`.
- All actions that involve a writable database are also wrapped in transactions with a `try/catch/finally` block to ensure `endTransaction()` is called.
- All other queries are wrapped in a `try/catch` block to catch any possible `SQLException` responses, which are logged as appropriate.
- I am calling `close()` on all `SQLiteDatabase` and `Cursor` objects that I'm using.

Most of these are things that used to throw background errors in the emulator until I corrected them, and when I run my app in the emulator I see no database errors of any kind any more. Yet running on my device I get the unhelpful "THIS SHOULD NEVER occur" errors seemingly for every single query I run, with no apparent ill effects.

Of course I'm just ignoring these for the time being, but I can't think of any other possible causes. My SQL statements are all valid, and most of my code is based on the official android tutorials such as the one [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Can anyone identify why I would be getting these errors? What other possible causes are there?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to incorrect usage of SQLite Api according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285486/1438915

This answer may help you in solving your problem.

check [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3.html)

Comment: That's just it though; I can't find anything I'm doing wrong. My `SQLiteOpenHelper` is a singleton, so as far as I'm aware multiple threads shouldn't be a problem, and even so I only have two basic classes, a `PreferenceActivity` and a `BroadcastReceiver`, and only the latter ever performs write operations, the other only performs `SELECT` based operations.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this error occurring when you try to access the sqlite db that is already closed.This may happen when multiple threads are accessing the db at the same time and one of the threads called the close. I just solved the problem by not closing the sqlite db at all. Hope this helps.